# Fail to save the file to the server side of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to save a file on the server side of where I am running the shiny app but for some reason I don't see the path when I try to save it.

Here is the code that I have it currently in the shiny app

library(shinyFiles)

```
shinySaveButton(id = 'download.scores', label =  'Save scores', title = "Save file as...", filetype = "csv")

observe({
    volumes <- c("wd"="/home/rstudio/data")
    shinyFileSave(input, "download.scores", roots=volumes, session=session)
    fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$download.scores)
    if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
      write.csv(score.show$scores, as.character(fileinfo$datapath), row.names = F)
    }
  })
```

When I try to save it, I see the blank path in the dialog box. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are running the app "locally" (i.e., not from shinyserver or similar), this usually happens to me when I misspell the "volume". Does "/home/rstudio/data" exist on your machine and is readable/writable?

Comment: Yes, the path "/home/rstudio/data" exists and I even tried a different location but with the same result. Don't know what is going on.

Comment: Strange. Just to be sure: you are running your app from RStudio, not from a shinyserver, right? Asking because if you are running it from shinyserver, then ShinyFiles will see the "file system" of the server, not that of the client. Thus "your" paths would not exist.