# What is the "shinySaveButton" equivalent in "ShinyWidgets"?

Tags: button, shiny

In my shiny app, I am using shinyWidgets (like, actionBttn) and they really look fantastic. However I couldn't find a shinyWidgets button that has a similar function to "shinySaveButton" for saving files. Although shinySaveButton is very functional and easy to use, it doesn't look nice among other shinyWidgets buttons. How can I sort this out?

Easy to code, with full file saving functionality:
'''
shinySaveButton("save", "Save file", "Save file as ...", 
                              filetype=list(csv="csv"))
'''

Looks great but no file saving functionality:
'''
actionBttn(inputId = "save", label = "Save", size="sm", color = "primary", 
                           style = "gradient", icon = icon("save"), block = FALSE)
'''

Answer (score 0):

If on the UI side you have got something like that

```
actionBttn(
    inputId = "save",
    label = "Go!",
    color = "primary",
    style = "bordered"
  )
```

Then on the server side you would be able to implement a logic that save a file:

```
observeEvent(input$save, {

write.csv(x = object_to_save, file = 'file.csv')

})
```

Obviously you have to define object_to_save first.

And this would save object_to_save in file.csv in your working directory, 
if you want to put it somewhre else, you should use the full path:
/here/is/my/path/file.csv

Also there is not only write.csv to save a file, there is a lot a function that allows you to save files in different format as save or saveRDS for example.

Comment: Sure, the issue is that the "shinySaveButton" provides a fully functional "save file window", like the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731269/fail-to-save-the-file-to-the-server-side-of-shiny-app and unfortunately I couldn't find a similar button in Shinywidgets. Thanks